# Getting java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [LBlndItmTmMthd

Tags: java, enums

I need a serious help in this issue. May be its very basic, but, I am not able to figure it out. I have a session EJB with one method which returns an enum array, i.e. `BlndItmTmMthd` array. When, I call the method in the client side, it gives me a `ClassCastException`.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [LBlndItmTmMthd
```

While debugging, I have found that the ejb method is correctly returning `BlndItmTmMthd` array by calling `BlndItmTmMthd.values()`. I am not able to find out the reason. Any idea will be helpful.

**Added content from a comment below**
AgreementSession.java is the EJB interface which contains the following method declaration:

```
BlndItmTmMthd[] getAllBlendedItemTimingMethods();
```

AgreementSessionEJB.java is the EJB that implements it.

```
public BlndItmTmMthd[] getAllBlendedItemTimingMethods() { 
    BlndItmTmMthd[] blendedItemTmingMethods = BlndItmTmMthd.values(); 
    return blendedItemTmingMethods; 
}
```

Now, at the client side, when I invoke the EJB method with the following code:

```
BlndItmTmMthd[] _timingMethods = 
             getLoanScheduleSetupSession().getAllBlendedItemTimingMethods();
```

I get that runtime exception.

Comment: please post some code : I can't help you with what you wrote.

Comment: AgreementSession.java is the EJB interface which contains the following method declaration. 
BlndItmTmMthd[] getAllBlendedItemTimingMethods();



AgreementSessionEJB.java is the EJB that implements it.
public BlndItmTmMthd[] getAllBlendedItemTimingMethods() {
        BlndItmTmMthd[] blendedItemTmingMethods = BlndItmTmMthd.values();
        return blendedItemTmingMethods;
    }



Now, at the client side, when I invoke the EJB method with the following code, 
BlndItmTmMthd[] _timingMethods = getLoanScheduleSetupSession().getAllBlendedItemTimingMethods();

I get that runtime exception.

Comment: I am not able to format the code!!!

Comment: @Raj, you should edit your question and put the code there.  You will be able to format it in the question.

Comment: @Justin, thanks for the information. I am totally new to Stack Overflow. So, not quite familiar with the processes. Anyway, as I can see that the question is edited and code is also in place as properly formatted.

Comment: @Raj At StackOverflow, you can edit your question to provide more information that the initial question.  Comments aren't meant for sharing any extra information.

Comment: Someone, please give me some idea about the actual problem that's causing that runtime exception.

Comment: @Raj, you are welcome.  Hopefully you find an answer.  Unfortunately I cannot help.

Comment: Can you please provide the code of BlndItmTmMthd? are you sure this is a client side error and not a server side error passed back to the client?

Comment: Are there any calls to toArray involved in code you havent't shown yet? Without parameters toArray returns an Object[], to return a BlndItmTmMthd[] you would have to pass in an Array of the right type. ([Ljava.lang.Object; is the jvm internal name of an Object[])

Comment: @Eyal BlndItmTmMthd is a very simple enum with three constants. It does not have any method/constructor defined in it. It seems a deserialization problem. When the BlndItmTmMthd[] array travels back server side to client side and gets deserialized, this problem occurs.

Comment: @Jörn, No, there is no toArray() call involved in my code. BlndItmTmMthd.values() is used instead to get the array.

Comment: Maybe this is not related to your question, but pardon me for my comment that I still think it is wise to avoid abbreviating classes name, since it could lead to confusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "[L" in your error tells you the problem - Java is failing to cast an *array* of Objects (that is, an Object[]) to an array of BlndItmTmMthds (a BlndItmTmMthd[]).

Is BlndItmTmMthd really a java.lang.Enum?

Comment: Yes, BlndItmTmMthd is an enum which contains three values.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the error implies that there is a failure to cast objects of type java.lang.Object to the Enum class, I believe there is a failure in the serialization and deserialization process when the response from the EJB is received at the client.

There are a couple of things that you might want to check:

- Is the Enum class BlndItmTmMthd available in the same classloader, or is it loaded twice?
- Does the generated stub of the EJB contain references to the Enum class or to java.lang.Object?

Comment: Need to check both the issued mentioned by you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have access to both the server and the client code. To trace down this issue you should insert logging statements of the form

```
logger.info(array.getClass().getCanonicalName());
```

at all places on the way from the `BlndItmTmMthd` to the `Object`. Then you can at least say at which point the conversion happens.